# Simple predicate that returns all possible splits of a list

Tags: prolog

In prolog, not using any predefined predicates, how might one go about finding all possible ways of splitting a list into 2 other lists.

For example, after running `all_possibilities([apple, ball, cat, dog], A, B).`
I want

```
A = []
B = [apple, ball, cat, dog]

A = [apple, ball, cat]
B = [dog]
...

A = [cat, dog]
B = [apple, ball]

A = [dog]
B = [apple, ball, cat] 

A = [apple, ball, cat, dog]
B = []
```

I have a rough idea of how to go about it theoretically but struggling to implement it.
I know I need to use recursion, and am trying to fix one item then assign the rest.

For example, start with list head in B, then recursively do the same for the tail so all elements are in B.
Then, when the last call exits, the tail should go in A.

Equivalently, this predicate would be true if A and B make up the first list.

I don't really know how to put it into words but any help is appreciated.
Let me know if I can add any more information and/or if I've made any errors.

(edit: although append is pretty close, my predicate would need append([2],[3,1],[1,2,3]) to return true for example, which append would not)

Comment: `all_possibilities(Zs, Xs,Ys) :- append(Xs, Ys, Zs).` But who chose that name?

Comment: @false lol - my apologies for the bad naming. It's quite late and for example

````
append(X,Y,[1,2,3]) gives

X = [],
Y = [1, 2, 3]

X = [1],
Y = [2, 3]

X = [1, 2],
Y = [3]

X = [1, 2, 3],
Y = []
````
But I want the cases `X =[2], Y = [1,3]`, etc. as well as the cases returned reversed, i.e. `X` and `Y` swapped. So all the different ways to split the list into 2 different lists.

Any idea on what I'd need to do? Thanks for the input

Comment: @15150776 - You want all ordered permutations of a list, plus each complementary list.